# How to search by Date in this DD/MM/YYYY format from TimeStamp column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I have a table called Transaction. One of the column name is `Time`,datatype is `TimeStamp`. So the data is looking like this `2015-01-14 23:22:11.000`.

Now I want to search by Date in where clause in this format `DD/MM/YYYY`

for example

```
select *
FROM Transaction
WHERE Date='25/12/2016' //   DD/MM/YYYY
```

Thanks

Comment: `Timestamp` in SQL Server has **absolutely NOTHING** to do with a date & time - it's just a binary server-side counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear, but it appears that you have the need to compare date data in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` against a timestamp column in your table.  One option is to use the `CONVERT` function to convert both the input and your timestamp column to a common `DATETIME` format, and then do the comparison.

```
SELECT *
FROM Transaction
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, TIME)) = CONVERT(DATETIME, '25/12/2016', 103)
```

This will return all records whose *date* components are `'2016-12-25'`.  Note that both sides of the comparison would have a time component set to midnight of that day.

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use canonical format (YYYY-MM-DD) on date columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transaction
WHERE Date=convert(datetime, '2016-12-25')
```

You can also use time ranges with canonical format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transaction
WHERE Date BETWEEN convert(datetime, '2016-12-25 00:00:00') 
               AND convert(datetime, '2016-12-25 23:59:59')
```

Comment: You're "canonical" format is **NOT** language independent - it will **break** depending on the language settings of your SQL Server. You should use *either* the `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` format (with a `T` between date and time), or use `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS` (**without** any dashes in the date part) to be independent of any language settings!

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
FROM Transaction
WHERE Date=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), '25/12/2016', 103)    DD/MM/YYYY
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, take parameter datatype as `varchar` and convert date like in the following SQL statement

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(25),CreateDate,103) as CreateDate, [UserID],[FirstName]+' '+[LastName] AS 'Name',[NomineeName],[City],[UserDocument]
FROM [dbo].[UserMaster] 
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(25),[CreateDate],103) between convert(varchar(25),@datefrom,103) and convert(varchar(25),@dateto,103)
```